# Unable to initialize variables before build?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on app which requires me to fetch data from the server (in my case a simple firebase real time database) and store the fetched data in map before the build method is called since i will be needing to use the map in the build method.

Here I have tried to recreate the error using a test code.

```
          import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
          import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
          import 'dart:convert';

          class Test extends StatefulWidget {
            @override
            Map<String, dynamic> livefeed;

            State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
              // TODO: implement createState
              return TestState();
            }
          }

          class TestState extends State<Test> {
            @override
            void initState() {
              http
                  .get('HERE GOES THE URL FOR THE DATABASE ,CANT DISCLOSE')
                  .then((http.Response response) {
                widget.livefeed = json.decode(response.body);
                print(widget.livefeed);
                print(widget.livefeed.length);
              });

              // TODO: implement initState
              super.initState();
            }

            @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                child: Text(widget.livefeed.toString()),
              );
            }
          }
```

The Console print :

```
{-Lh7FJV_7FIXgEUUS3Is: {skill: Andriod dev, target: Just Entered The Lab., 
username: test}, -Lh7RKgw3K2ZuKjrBZd2: {skill: Andriod dev, target: Just 
Entered The Lab., username: test}}
I/flutter ( 7078): 2
```

Yet my UI shows null when i try to display the map on the screen
inside the build method.

I am aware that initState() method is called before the Build() method yet initialization fails, the debug console confirms that data is being fetched yet it fails to be printed on the screen implying build is being called before the values are initialized .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put this inside a setState method
`widget.livefeed = json.decode(response.body);`

And ofcourse you need to handle what to show while the `widget.livefeed` is null. As you said even initState() method is called before the Build() method, `http.get()` is an async function. You can't assure that it will finish before build method is called BECAUSE IT IS AN ASYNC FUNCTION.

You can handle it like this

```
Text(widget.livefeed!=null?widget.livefeed.toString():'some default text like loading...'),
```